# display database field in textbox

Tags: php

I am trying to display a database input in a textbox for editing.  I cant seem to get it working?!
The page links from a forum post edit button.  Firstly, I don't know how to get the database info for that particular field to be displayed and also I don't understand how to make sure the post that the user clicks to edit is the post that is displayed.

My code looks like this

```
<?php
#data preparation for the query 
$id=$_GET['id']; 

# selects title and description fields from database 
$sql = "SELECT a_answer FROM $tbl_name WHERE question_id='$id'"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

?> 
<h3>Edit</h3> <form action="save_edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="myForm" />   
<table>     

<tr>       
<td><b>Answer</b></td>       
<td><textarea cols="80%" rows="10" name="a_answer"><?php echo $row['$a_answer']; ?></textarea></td>   
  </tr>  
   </table>   <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<? echo $id; ?>">   
   <input name="enter" type="submit" value="Edit"> </form>  

  <?php mysql_close(); ?>
```

Comment: `$rows` contains row and you are usign `$row` a suggestion as well How about going with some good tutorial

Comment: yep, fixed that and still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors in your code: Firstly, you are using `row` instead of `rows`. The second is the dollar sign you 're using when accessing the field. The code below should work, provided your database query is correct.

```
<?php
#data preparation for the query 
$id=$_GET['id']; 

# selects title and description fields from database 
$sql = "SELECT a_answer FROM $tbl_name WHERE question_id='$id'"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

?> 
<h3>Edit</h3> <form action="save_edit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="myForm" />   
<table>     

<tr>       
<td><b>Answer</b></td>       
<td><textarea cols="80%" rows="10" name="a_answer"><?php echo $rows['a_answer']; ?></textarea></td>   
  </tr>  
   </table>   <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<? echo $id; ?>">   
   <input name="enter" type="submit" value="Edit"> </form>  

  <?php mysql_close(); ?>
```

Another way to go about things would be to use prepared statements, and let PHP and MySQL quess the correct type. [Here can be found](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/356.cfm) a simple example.

Comment: No problem. You should indicate that this answer is the solution to your problem by accepting it, so others can potentially benefit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

confirm if the question id is integer or varchar in your database. if it is integer then remove the single quotes. ( just a hint may it helps you. ).
One more thing you do not need to put the multipart in your form if you not uploading any files another tip form me.